# How can i install Docker in Deepin 15.11?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**The Fist Problem was that i couldn't run the Dockers container in my pc probaly 'cause the version of the SO is 15.11. - I just found ways of install in 15.9 or below. - And i really need the docker or other similar service**

Comment: from my understanding, deepin is a descendant of debian, so you can probably use similar instructions as debian: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you have already installed it or not but hoping that it will be helpful for others at least

Please go through the below GitHub link it helped me installing docker on deepin20 Beta

https://gist.github.com/madkoding/3f9b02c431de5d748dfde6957b8b85ff